# Reading text from Mac OS terminal window through Java code?

Tags: java, macos, terminal

This is the code I am using:

```
String cmd="tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd  "+ path +" && "+ command +" \" ";
System.out.println(cmd);
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("osascript","-e",cmd);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
```

It's giving null. How can I read from the terminal window?

Comment: Have you tried something like Runtime.getRuntime().exec()?

Comment: i tried with Runtime class also Kai Huppmann .but it is giving message like 
"tab 1 of window id 181" in first iteration and second time it is giving Null

Comment: Please provide any solution that can read from terminal window

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/).

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;

class CMDTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{
         ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         CommandLine command = new CommandLine("/bin/sh");
         command.addArguments(new String[] {
           "-c",
           "ls '-al'"
         },false);
         DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
         PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
         exec.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
         exec.execute(command);
         System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
       }
       catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("error");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: i trued with this solution but it is throwing exception on executing "exec.execute(command);"

Comment: What is the exception? Did you install the Apache Commons Exec jar into your classpath?